# Submitting Apple iOS app with previously used template

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, templates

I've created an app specific to a certain business model and now I am helping a select group of other business teams by essentially using the same app template but with their info and content as they desire. Will Apple reject this? Everything I have seen so far from Apple is very vague.

"Repeated submission of similar apps
Submitting several apps that are essentially the same ties up the App Review process and risks the rejection of your apps. Improve your review experience — and the experience of your future users — by thoughtfully combining your apps into one."

If anyone has more insight into this, please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Apple would reject it if you submit them with the same team. In my case, my fifth or fourth one is rejected due to this .

Comment: When you say app template, Im guessing you referring to the design styling. Well, my experience is a little different from @Horst. We have design library which share very similar components for the multiple apps (with different content of course), yet submission is approved. Again it depends how much % of similarity are we talking here. Are you 100% same design with different context or 70% similar design and 30% new screens new context?

Comment: In my case, I am using a seed project for showing company leaflets. and I edit the logos / name / tnc etc. only.

Comment: @TommyLeong So the client gets to customize the app from the admin website I have created and so they can add pages and edit all the content on each page. So each page's content will be unique to each business client's desires. But, the design of each tab bar page will always be the same just different content on each page. And the tab bar names will also likely be the same "Home" "Media" etc. and the same icons. Would it help to use different names/icons here? Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Can't tell if that would help, but maybe you could help to shape your client towards a better direction in consolidating their application (if they share the same purpose?) It helps them better in managing their applications and their user will be happy for not having multiple apps on device. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @TommyLeong Appreciate your thoughts. At no point would any person ever have more than 1 app on their device so it will not actually consolidate. Each app is for an individual business and team serving different purposes specific to that team, but a same UI as other apps I am posting for other businesses. And sharing many of the same functionalities. Sounds like a gray area. Gonna have to take some risk and post how it goes back in here to hopefully help others.